# What happens in background when passing parameters as variable in a function

Tags: function, delphi, parameters

I readed some theorical information about this in some places, but I didn't understand yet...

Let's supose I have this functions and procedures:

```
function ProcessVars1(var param1: type1; var param2: type2; var param3: type3): Boolean;
function ProcessVars2(var param1: type1; var param2: type2; var param3: type3): Boolean;
function ProcessVars3(var param1: type1; var param2: type2; var param3: type3): Boolean;
function ProcessVarsX(var param1: type1; var param2: type2; var param3: type3): Boolean;

function ProcessVars(const x: Integer; var param1: type1; var param2: type2; var param3: type3): Boolean;
var
  Res: Boolean;
begin
  case x of
    1: Res := ProcessVars1(param1, param2, param3);
    2: Res := ProcessVars2(param1, param2, param3);
    3: Res := ProcessVars3(param1, param2, param3);
    ...
  end;
  Result := Res;
end;

procedure DoSomething;
var
  x: integer;
  var1: type1;
  var2: type2;
  var3: type3;
begin
  // Determine X
  x := 1;  
  if ProcessVars(x, var1, var2, var3) then
  begin
    // Use var1, var2 and var3
  end;
end;
```

What I'd like to know is when calling the "DoSomething" procedure, are variables var1, var2 and var3 created in memory only one time, or 3 times?

Is there a way to avoid creating the variables each time the function is called? I mean, ProcessVars and ProcessVarsX only change the variable content, without creating it again in memory?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the question at all. A local variable is created, and destroyed, each time the function in which it declared is called.

Comment: Thanks @DavidHeffernan! But then, is there a way to avoid creating the variables each time the function is called? I mean, ProcessVars and ProcessVarsX only change the variable content, without creating it again in memory?

Comment: Read David's comment carefully. "the function which it declared" is "DoSomething" in your code, not "Process..".

Comment: Ok, let me understand better... So the variables var1, var2 and var3 are created in memory one time by the "DoSomething" procedure, and the other functions ProcessVars and ProcessVarsX only uses the same memory allocated spaces? I am right?

Comment: Since they are var declared in ProcessVars, they are passed by reference.

Comment: Ok, thank you David Heffernan, Sertac Akyuz and LU RD!

Comment: If you really want to know what the compiler does behind the scenes, you can always use the debugger to view the compiled assembly code for each function call.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I think the asker isn't quite at that level yet. And surely you don't need to resort to reverse engineering to understand lifetime of variables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`DoSomething()` declares four local variables - `x`, `var1`, `var2` and `var3`.  These variables are created every time `DoSomething()` is called, and disappear when `DoSomething()` exits.

When `DoSomething()` calls `ProcessVars()` it makes a **copy** of the *value* of `x` since `x` is being passed **by value**, but it passes the **memory addresses** of `var1`, `var2`, `var3` since they are being passed by **`var` reference** instead.

When `ProcessVars()` passes its `param1`, `param2`, and `param3` parameters to the various `ProcessVars...()` functions, they are again being passed by **`var` reference**, so only the memory addresses are being passed around.  The physical variables still reside in `DoSomething()` only, they are not being copied in memory.

Comment: this is exacly what I thought. Thank you for making it clear!

Comment: For more information, please read: http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-pointers.html